# Obligatory field check ignored if TABBED BLOCK used

Tags: abap

I have the following program.

```
REPORT zz_tab_strip_obligatory.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF TABBED BLOCK tab FOR 20 LINES.
SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (54) tab1 USER-COMMAND tab1 DEFAULT SCREEN 100.
SELECTION-SCREEN TAB (54) tab2 USER-COMMAND tab2 DEFAULT SCREEN 200.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK tab.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 100 AS SUBSCREEN.
PARAMETERS:
  p1 TYPE i.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 100.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 200 AS SUBSCREEN.
PARAMETERS:
  p2 TYPE i OBLIGATORY.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 200.

INITIALIZATION.
  tab1 = 'Tab1'.
  tab2 = 'Tab2'.
```

The first tab has no obligatory fields. The second one on the other hand does.

The problem I am having is that if the user does not go to the second tab and instead of it starts the program immediately with F8 then the obligatory check for the parameters `p2` is not performed at all. It looks like all of the events like `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` are executed only for the current tab ergo for the displayed subscreen.

Is there any way to work around it? My current solution right now is sadly getting rid of `OBLIGATORY` keywords and making the checks after `START-OF-SELECTION` (my real program has many tabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a direct solution to the selection screen obligatory issue. [Here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1700945) is a similar topic. However, you can store all the obligatory parameters in an internal table. At the Start-of-selection, loop through them and check them.

```
DATA: BEGIN OF gt_obl_fields OCCURS 0,
    fname TYPE char10,
    ftext type char50,
END OF gt_obl_fields.

INITIALIZATION.
 tab1 = 'Tab1'.
 tab2 = 'Tab2'.

 gt_obl_fields-fname = 'P2'.
 gt_obl_fields-ftext = text-001.
 APPEND gt_obl_fields.
 "...
START-OF-SELECTION.
  LOOP AT gt_obl_fields .
    ASSIGN (gt_obl_fields-fname) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_field>).
    IF <fs_field> IS ASSIGNED AND <fs_field> IS INITIAL..
      CONCATENATE gt_obl_fields-ftext 'field must be filled!' INTO data(lv_message).
      MESSAGE lv_message TYPE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is what I am actually doing as a workaround. It is hard to believe, that this cannot be handled in some other neater way without getting rid of `OBLIGATORY` markups.